# how to get the profileid of contact through account

Tags: apex, trigger, case, list, map

I need to get the profile id of the contact for whom the case is created using Accountid.
Here follows my code:

```
public without sharing class CaseEmailtoDealers_CLS {
    public static void emailToDealers(list < Case > listCase) {
        // Functionality : Sending mail to Delaerwhen the Case lookup is filled 
        //wont work in case of bulk loading  
        if (listCAse.size() == 1 && listCAse[0].Dealer__c != null) {
            // Verifying there is only one case in the context
             List<Account> acc2 = [Select Id, country__c, SecondaryEmail__c from Account where Id = :listCAse[0].Dealer__c];

               List<Contact> con2 = [Select Id from Contact where AccountId = :listCAse[0].Dealer__c];
             List<User> potentialUsers = [SELECT Id, ProfileId FROM User where ContactId IN :con2];


  Map<String, User> emailToUserMap = new Map<String, User>();
  for (User u : potentialUsers) {
    emailToUserMap.put(u.ProfileId, u);
  }
  User creator = emailToUserMap.get(System.Label.Rforce_care_CommunityServiceProfile);
  System.debug('### creator creator creator ### with CaseId value =' + creator );
  }
  }
```

But the problem is what happen when an account has more contact with the same profile id. I need to take an particular  contact with the particular profile id using account id in case.

Comment: What's the problem? Are you not populating contact lookup on the case detail?

Comment: @Satish what is the condition for that particular contact record. If not then simply use `LIMIT`. For example: `Select Id from Contact where AccountId = :listCAse[0].Dealer__c LIMIT 1`. And your profile query would be `SELECT Id, ProfileId FROM User where ContactId = :con2[0].id`.

Comment: @ Rohit Mourya an account can have n number of contacts. so we can't limit it.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty i dont have lookup on the contact.I need to get through contact.

Comment: @Sathish Why don't you store all Contact Id's in `Set` and then run query on `Profile`.` Set` always has distinct elements in it. So if you enter duplicate `id`'s, it won't take it.

Comment: Who is creating the case on behalf of the account? Are you having your account contacts create cases ?

Comment: There is a standard lookup to Contact from Case, aren't you using that? What is your relationship between Case to Contact?

Comment: @abhi An agent will be creating case behalf of the dealer.

Comment: @SantanuHalder yes there is standard lookup on case. an agent updates only account...

Comment: Okay then what is your design to fetch the correct Contact from that account? There could be multiple contact under that account.